# Three finger tap delay on touchpad

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

When trying to make use of a three finger tap to perform the equivalent of a mouse middle click on my laptop's touch pad, I notice a delay in the action in being executed. I use it mostly for opening and closing tabs in Firefox, and sometimes the delay is very long, up to 3 seconds. This is on Ubuntu 21.10 with Wayland (using X doesn't change anything).

Despite this, I tried using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with both Wayland and X and didn't run into this issue; in general the touch pad three finger taps were far more responsive, and so were the single finger taps as well. Does his have something to do with the LTS being on a different libinput driver version? If so how can I get my 21.10 version of Ubuntu to use that one instead?

Relevant output of `sudo libinput list-devices`

```
Device:           PNP0C50:00 06CB:CDAA Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event9
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             137x62mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

Comment: Might also be related to your hardware - include output from `sudo libinput list-devices` in your question.